# Template doesn't work in Symfony - how to connect a new function?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm creating an app and I want to enable users to change their data and password. I've created an email changing form and it works, but I've got a problem with password.
I've got a page localhost:8000/user/{id} and here the buttons: edit email and edit password. Edit email is working and when I click on editing password - I got a blank page on localhost:8000/user/{id}/change_password
([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2J2V.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NirWY.png)). Th PassType doesn't show there.

There are no syntax error on localhost:8000/user/{id} and localhost:8000/user/{id}/change_password.

I've added a function edit_pass to UserController, crated PassType (where is the form to change password) and make a template edit_password.html.twig.

I don't know where is the problem. I did the same thing as with other Forms which work. I've tried to clear the edit_password template (I've just left the base_html there and put some text) cause I've thought there is a problem in it, but it was still a blank page on localhost:8000/user/{id}/change_password.

PassType:

```
<?php
/*
 * Password type.
 */

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class PassType.
 */
class PassType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Builds the form.
     *
     * This method is called for each type in the hierarchy starting from the
     * top most type. Type extensions can further modify the form.
     *
     * @see FormTypeExtensionInterface::buildForm()
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder The form builder
     * @param array                $options The options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add(
            'password',
            RepeatedType::class,
            [
                'type' => PassType::class,
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => ['max_length' => 40],
                'first_options' => ['label' => 'label.password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'label.repeat_password'],
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Configures the options for this type.
     *
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver The resolver for the options
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => User::class]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the prefix of the template block name for this type.
     *
     * The block prefix defaults to the underscored short class name with
     * the "Type" suffix removed (e.g. "UserProfileType" => "user_profile").
     *
     * @return string The prefix of the template block name
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

edit_password.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    {{ 'title_password_edit'|trans({'%id%': user.id|default('')}) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1 class="display-4 d-flex justify-content-center">{{ 'title_password_edit'|trans({'%id%': user.id|default('')}) }}</h1>
    {{ form_start(form, { method: 'PUT', action: url('password_edit', {id: user.id}) }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div class="form-group row float-sm-right">
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'action_save'|trans }}" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row float-sm-left">
        <a href="{{ url('user_index') }}" class="btn btn-link">
            {{ 'action_back_to_list'|trans }}
        </a>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

and part of UserController whith edit_pass function

```
 /**
     * Edit Password.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request    HTTP request
     * @param \App\Entity\User                          $user       User entity
     * @param \App\Repository\UserRepository            $repository User repository
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response HTTP response
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     *
     * @Route(
     *     "/{id}/change_password",
     *     methods={"GET", "PUT"},
     *     requirements={"id": "[1-9]\d*"},
     *     name="password_edit",
     * )
     */
    public function edit_pass(Request $request, User $user, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, UserRepository $repository): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(PassType::class, $user, ['method' => 'PUT']);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user->setPassword(
                $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('password')->getData()
                )
            );
            $repository->save($user);

            $this->addFlash('success', 'message.updated_successfully');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_show', array('id' => $this->getUser()->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render(
            'user/edit_password.html.twig',
            [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'user' => $user,
            ]
        );
    }
```

I'm also adding the user/show.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    {{ 'label_detail_users'|trans({'%id%': user.id|default('')}) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1 class="display-4 d-flex justify-content-center">{{ 'label_detail_users'|trans({'%id%': user.id|default('')}) }}</h1>
    {% if users is defined and users|length %}
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ 'label_user_id'|trans }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'label_email'|trans }}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ users.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ users.email }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ url('user_edit', {id: users.id}) }}" title="{{ 'edit_email'|trans }}">
                {{ 'edit_email'|trans }}
            </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ url('password_edit', {id: users.id}) }}" title="{{ 'edit_password'|trans }}">
                {{ 'edit_password'|trans }}
            </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ url('user_index') }}" title="{{ 'action_back_to_list'|trans }}">
                {{ 'action_back_to_list'|trans }}
            </a>
        </p>

    {% else %}
        <p>
            {{ 'message_item_not_found'|trans }}
        </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "app seems not to read the template"? What happens, and when (initial page load or after submit)?

Comment: So I'm going from user/show to user/edit_password and display the PassType (to change the password). But page under site localhost:8000/user/{id}/change_password is clear (just the white page). It seems like the template is not read by app (even the navbar from base.html.twig doesn's show)

Comment: In reference to your screen shot, your IDE will not be able to find where the function is called, as it is done dynamically by the router and so it flags it as unused. This is nothing to be concerned about and can be safely ignored.

Comment: No errors? Are you in `dev` or `prod`?

Comment: I've edited the post and added th screen of what I get after clicking "edit password".

Comment: I usually get all of the syntax errors and now I'm confused why I don't have any

Comment: Are you in dev or prod environment?

Comment: I'm in dev environment

Comment: Can you share more details about your problem? Please add all clarification in text form to your question, don't use only screenshots to describe the problem. Also, please explain what you've tried to resolve the problem

Comment: I've edited the post. I hope it's more clear now. 
I'm just unable to display the PassType - form to change the password. And the page with this form is blank - It didn't even heritage navbar from base_html)

Comment: How does the blank page happen? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Well, I've just the usual steps I've did before with creating the form - created a function, template and form. And then it happened :x 
Actually, I'm so new in it that I'm not even sure how could I debug it

Comment: vardump + die could already help. Also, have a look at the status code of your response: if it is 500, you need to check your server's error log. Or install the profiler (https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html) to get more information about the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You produced an endless loop - its `PasswordType` in your `RepeatedType`. `PassType` is the name of your whole Form - you see the problem?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder->add(
        'password',
        RepeatedType::class,
        [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => ['max_length' => 40],
            'first_options' => ['label' => 'label.password'],
            'second_options' => ['label' => 'label.repeat_password'],
        ]
    );
}
```

And may I ask why you limit the length of a password?

Comment: And the limited length is because of the task I've got. I'm using some instructions I found in the Internet to build this app and this limitation was there

Comment: my pleasure. from a security stand point you should not limit your users from using whole sentences as password. some companies limiting the length to spare some cpu cycles with brute force attacks (hashing is (and should be)  expensive)